# How to cache YouTube videos?

Tags: caching, youtube

There are times I watched a particular video multiple times, Is there a way to cache videos on the DNS level thus whenever I open a video which is cached, the DNS server loads the video from the local server thus having no change on the client side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DNS server resolves and can cache only the ip address of the server, not the content hosted on the ip address.
For caching the content of a given url, you need to use some proxy cache server eg. `squid`.